# Issue with upload app to the app store

Tags: app-store

I have an issue with upload my app to the app store.
I try to upload it many times, but 
I get the error message, when I upload my app I get  the following error message :

**(this action could not be completed.try again.(-22421))**

I check many questions in stack overflow. Everyone says, that I must wait and  upload app next time, because the problem with server apple. But I have get this issue 4 days and can't upload it. 
Could you please help me to solve this issue? Thank you for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

try this way..

- build your app
- archive your app
- create .ipa of your app
- upload your app from **Application Loader**

Comment: thank you very much my friend ,  also i do it but also have the same issue like the Xcode